# Why is $\sqrt{X}\times\sqrt{X}=X$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic

Today I was solving the limit $(\ln(x))/(2*(x^{1/2})$ but then faced the step after applying the derivation that ended up with $(1/x)/(1/x^{1/2})$ and the result of that was $1/x^{1/2}$. When I asked a friend to explain why he said it's because the $X$ is replaced with $\sqrt X * \sqrt X$. So does that means that $\sqrt X * \sqrt X = X$? if so can someone explain why?

Comment: What do you know about $\sqrt X$ ?

Comment: That's basically how $\sqrt{x}$ ia defined.

Comment: $\sqrt{X}$ is a number with the property that if you multiply it by itself you get $X$.  So yes, it's always true that $\sqrt X\times\sqrt X=X$.

Comment: @GregoryGrant Yes, if $X>0$.

Comment: @5xum If $X<0$ then $\sqrt{X}$ is undefined.  I assume we're working in the real numbers here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is the definition of square root. A square root of a real number $x\ge0$ is another real number $a$ such that
$$
a^2=x.
$$
If $x>0$ it has two square roots, denoted as 
$$
\pm\sqrt x,
$$
where it is understood that $\sqrt x>0$. Then
$$
\sqrt x\,\sqrt x=(\sqrt x)^2=x.
$$

Comment: "The square root of a real number $x\ge0$ is another" NONNEGATIVE "real number $a$ such that $a^2=x.$"